# How can I sniff GPIO traffic?

Tags: gpio

I've got a DHT21 Temperature & Humidity sensor, and was just curious to spy on the raw GPIO traffic if it's possible.  (Everything is working correctly - i.e. I am able to poll the device.)

What tools/utilities can be used to spy on GPIO traffic - some of my searches suggest that tcpdump can actually be used - but I'm unsure what 'interface' would be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) to sniff GPIO activity.

pigpio may be pre-installed on the standard  OS.

If `pigs  t` returns  just a number  it is installed  otherwise  try

`sudo apt install pigpio`

For accurate results the traffic  should be  less  than 100 k bits per second (so you might have to slow a SPI or I2C bus).

Try graphical based [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or the terminal based [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) to view the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I use a logic analyzer, it is very handy and only requires one USB port. I use Linux and normally have about 6 to 8 workspaces open so I put the logic analyzer in one and the others are available for whatever such as the compiler, terminal for Pi, etc. A china clone of the 8 channel 24 Mhz seele is under $10.00 US There is a lot of software to operate it. Depending on the software it will decode many of the protocols such as I2C, SPI, Async and many others. Timing etc is a very easy to measure, I just set two cursors and read it on the screen. It does not have a lot of input protection but using care and or input resistors help a lot. I found this as my first google hit: "USB Logic Analyzer Device Set USB Cable 8CH 24MHz 24MHz for ARM FPGA M100" for about $8.00 and $3.00 Shipping. Good luck!